# Set the boundary for calculating the expectation of joint probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-expectation

From the joint pdf below, I need to find $E(X)$.

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
8x^2e^{-2y}, & 0<x<y\\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I know that
    $$E(X)=\int xf(x)dx$$
so I calculate $f(x)$ first. Since $0<x<y,\,$ I set the boundary $y>0$ or $0<y<\infty$. But I'm not sure I got it right.
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty 8x^2e^{-2y} \,dy= 4x^2$$

I subtitute this result to $E(X)$ by setting the boundary from $0$ to $\infty$. But I got diverge result.
 $$E(X)=\int_0^\infty x4x^2\,dx=\int_0^\infty 4x^3\,dx=\text{diverge}$$
I guess I set the boundary wrong. But I'm not be able to figure it out.

How am I supposed to set the right boundary? Did I get the step correctly?

Comment: No, the marginal pdf $f_X(x)$ equals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 8x^2 e^{-2y}  \cdot \mathbf{1}[0 < x < y ] \; dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary should be $x<y<\infty$

Therefore:

$f(x)= \int^{\infty}_{x}{8x^2e^{-2y}}dy=8x^2 \int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-2y}dy=8x^2[-\frac{1}2e^{-2y}|^\infty_x]=4x^2e^{-2x}$

Now you should be able to find $E(X)$ (Which should be $\frac{3}2$)

Comment: So, as for f(y), the boundary is 0<x<y, correct?

Comment: Correct. to find $f(y)$ the integral would look like $\int^y_0{f(x,y)}dx$